# Cannot install socket.io in SuSE 12 patch 2, anyone see this?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Node version v6.10.3,
SuSE 12, SP2.
install socket.io failed.

```
# npm install --save socket.io     

npm ERR! Linux 4.4.62-1.1.venvr.imsdk.gf9be3f4-default
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "--save" "socket.io"
npm ERR! node v6.10.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo

npm ERR! getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /our path ....../npm-debug.log
```

Following is npm-debug-log

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '--save',
1 verbose cli   'socket.io' ]
2 info using npm@3.10.10
3 info using node@v6.10.3
4 silly loadCurrentTree Starting
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 silly fetchPackageMetaData socket.io
8 silly fetchNamedPackageData socket.io
9 silly mapToRegistry name socket.io
10 silly mapToRegistry using default registry
11 silly mapToRegistry registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
12 silly mapToRegistry data Result {
12 silly mapToRegistry   raw: 'socket.io',
12 silly mapToRegistry   scope: null,
12 silly mapToRegistry   escapedName: 'socket.io',
12 silly mapToRegistry   name: 'socket.io',
12 silly mapToRegistry   rawSpec: '',
12 silly mapToRegistry   spec: 'latest',
12 silly mapToRegistry   type: 'tag' }
13 silly mapToRegistry uri https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
14 verbose request uri https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
15 verbose request no auth needed
16 info attempt registry request try #1 at 3:38:59 PM
17 verbose request id e51e8566dc6bcd5d
18 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
19 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443
20 info attempt registry request try #2 at 3:39:09 PM
21 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
22 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443
23 info attempt registry request try #3 at 3:40:09 PM
24 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at errnoException (dns.js:33:15)
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData  error for socket.io { Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at errnoException (dns.js:33:15)
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData   code: 'EAI_AGAIN',
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData   errno: 'EAI_AGAIN',
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData   syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData   hostname: 'registry.npmjs.org',
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData   host: 'registry.npmjs.org',
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData   port: 443 }
26 silly rollbackFailedOptional Starting
27 silly rollbackFailedOptional Finishing
28 silly runTopLevelLifecycles Finishing
29 silly install printInstalled
30 verbose stack Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443
30 verbose stack     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
30 verbose stack     at errnoException (dns.js:33:15)
30 verbose stack     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
31 verbose cwd /our path ......
32 error Linux 4.4.62-1.1.venvr.imsdk.gf9be3f4-default
33 error argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "--save" "socket.io"
34 error node v6.10.3
35 error npm  v3.10.10
36 error code EAI_AGAIN
37 error errno EAI_AGAIN
38 error syscall getaddrinfo
39 error getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443
40 error If you need help, you may report this error at:
40 error     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
41 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Any suggestions please ?

Comment: What does `dig registry.npmjs.org` show? It appears there is a problem resolving the npm registry hostname.

Comment: ; <<>> DiG 9.9.9-P1 <<>> registry.npmjs.org
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

Comment: @mscdex i think you are right, on that machine i cannot even ping yahoo.com